# What is a compact way of writing that an element of a set $A$ is not an element of set $B$?

Tags: general-topology, notation

What is a compact way of writing that an element belongs to a set $A$ but is not in set $B$? In other words

$$
x \in A, x\notin B
$$

At first I thought this might be

$$
x \in A\setminus B
$$

but it doesn't seem quite logically correct.

Comment: Why not?  Looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ x \in A\setminus B\ $ means $\ x\in A\ $ and $\ x \notin B.$

Recently I've also used $\ A-B\ $ as an alternative notation for $\ A\setminus B\ $ without complaints, so I think this is acceptable notation also.

Comment: In some contexts $A-B$ will be interpreted as the Minkowski sum (well, difference in this case), $\{a-b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$. Of course, this happens when it makes sense (e.g. in a vector space or in general some abelian group).

Comment: You're not wrong, but I'm not wrong either. See for example: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html

Comment: Did I say that you're wrong?

Comment: Haha, well played, Sir. Well played. You've out-witted me this time. But there's always next time...

Comment: I have developed a tendency to use $A-B$ as the set theoretic difference and $A \setminus B$ as a differerence operator in more complicated categories. For example if $A$ is a graph and $B$ is a subgraph (and if, like some topologists, you think of graphs as topological objects, e.g. as 1 dimensional CW complexes) then $A \setminus B$ is the closure of $A-B$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct because of the definition of set difference.

Comment: sorry, i somehow got befuddled.

Comment: For clarity you *might* want to write:  $x \in (A \setminus B)$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition $(x\in A\setminus B)$ goes for $(x\in A\cap B^\complement)$

This means $x\in A$ and ($x\in B^\complement\iff x\notin B$) which is exactly what you want.